# Infinite scroll and image gallery issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I have set up infinite scroll on a website I am building here: http://richardgordoncook.com/fg/

I am using a Wordpress plugin for an image gallery, which I've manipulated a little to have hover overs of the filenames etc. This all works fine, until the infinite scroll kicks in and any posts after the first page seem to stop using the gallery functionality and really any javascript at all.

Any ideas? You'll get an idea when you test it out on the site link above.

Comment: I'm getting several JS errors in the page, possibly because scripts are being loaded in the wrong order or are not found.

Comment: Oh really? Firebug and Chrome Dev tools show no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements added by the infinite scroll need to have the JavaScript events wired to them after they are created. <strike>See jQuery's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function for more information on how to do this easily.</strike>

Essentially, you replace

```
$('.myclass').mouseover(function(){})
```

with

```
$('.myclass').live('mouseover', function(){});
```

And jQuery will automatically wire up all the extra events after the new dom elements are added to the page.

### UPDATE

Ok, forget the `.live()` approach. It looks like the plugin has a callback function that is raised whenever it adds new new elements to the page.

```
$(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback]);
```

The callback function is documented as

```
function(arrayOfNewElems){
 
     // optional callback when new content is successfully loaded in.
 
     // keyword `this` will refer to the new DOM content that was just added.
     // as of 1.5, `this` matches the element you called the plugin on (e.g. #content)
     //                   all the new elements that were found are passed in as an array
 
}
```

You should use this callback to wire up the event handlers to the new elements on the page. It would look something like this

```
function(elements)
{
    $(elements).mouseover(function(){});
    $(elements).mouseout(function(){});
}
```

Depending on what you need to do, you may need to use a `for` loop and iterate over each item individually instead of acting on them as one batch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could probably do this for the hover over stuff, but perhaps editing the gallery plugin will be a bit risky.

Comment: Also, the hover over stuff is looking good, although with this:

`<script>
$('a:has(.image-active)').live('hover', function() { 
    $('.image-active', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}, 1); 
},function() { 
    $('.image-active', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}, 1); 
});
</script>`

doesn't seem to turn the opacity to 0 when I hover off. Must be the second function() but can't figure it out.

Comment: Managed to get it with this:

`<script>
$('a:has(.image-active)').live('mouseover', function() { 
    $('.image-active', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}, 1); 
});
</script>
<script>
$('a:has(.image-active)').live('mouseout', function() { 
    $('.image-active', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}, 1); 
});
</script>`

Still stuck on the gallery stuff - I'm guessing I'll have to go through it all?

Comment: The gallery plugin was a whole $(window).load so I took everything inside that, and turned it into a function.

 `$(window).load(function() {
              portfolioSlideshow()
  });`

But now I need to keep recalling that function when the next page loads within the infinitescroll. Any ideas? I can't use .live on a .load function so any clue about a callback? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I left you hanging. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this. Worked wonderfully. I'm still a little stuck with the portfolioSlideshow now, however as that also needs to be called back when the infinitescroll runs each time. With the mouseover,mouseout - that all makes sense, but the portfolioSlideshow currently sits as `$(window).load(function() { portfolioSlideshow() });` so any thoughts on how I would recall this? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm still stuck here, any help?

Comment: @Richard Cant you just call `portfolioSlideshow` in the infinate scroll callback too? I tried looking at the site again and couldnt see where the code was.

Comment: Yep, but wasn't sure how to write it in.

See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763308/infinite-scroll-and-the-callback