# Infinite scroll and the callback

Tags: jquery, callback, infinite-scroll

Apologies if this conflicts with a previous post of mine, but I am pretty stuck with the whole callback function of infinite scroll that hopefully someone can help me out.

I'm using the Portfolio Slideshow Pro (http://madebyraygun.com/wordpress/plugins/portfolio-slideshow-pro/) for Wordpress combined with Infinite Scroll.

This is what my infinite scroll JS looks like:

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('.rest-of-content');

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.wp-paginate',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '.wp-paginate li a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.single-fg-post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      bufferPX: 20,
      loading: {
          msgText: 'Fetching more gold...',
          finishedMsg: 'We\'ve ran out of gold!',
          img: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ajax-loader-black.gif'
        }

    });

  });
</script>
```

The slideshow plugin is a whole $(window).load so I took everything inside that, and turned it into a function.

```
$(window).load(function() { portfolioSlideshow() });
```

But now I need to callback that function each time the new set of posts load as although the infinitescroll is working, the JS on the slideshow aren't.

Can someone please help me add the function I created to the callback of infinitescroll so it reloads the function each time new data is loaded in?

Thanks so much in advance.

-R

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.wp-paginate',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.wp-paginate li a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.single-fg-post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    bufferPX: 20,
    loading: {
        msgText: 'Fetching more gold...',
        finishedMsg: 'We\'ve ran out of gold!',
        img: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ajax-loader-black.gif'
    }
},
function(arrayOfNewElems)
{
    portfolioSlideshow();
});
```

This will call `portfolioSlideshow()` every time the infinitescroll plugin loads new data.

Comment: Hi Jeff,
Thanks so much for this. It's now not breaking at all, which is great, but it still doesn't seem to bring the portfolioSlideshow into play > http://goo.gl/0KEWc. I'm wondering now if the `portfolioSlideshow();` function isn't perhaps wrapped properly as when I type portfolioslideshow() into the console it states: portfolioSlideshow is not defined. Hmm - perhaps something I need to work on. Thanks for all your help, Jeff.

Comment: Got it the code working, but it doesn't seem like the sliding function is working. Have contacted the forums on the slideshow's site for help on this. Thanks, Jeff.