# Infinite Scroll Callback issue with custom jQuery function

Tags: jquery, scroll, callback, infinite, masonry

I have a page that uses the Isotope Masonry layout combined with Infinite Scroll. On that page I am also dynamically loading images into some divs using jquery .load in a function (BlogImageLoad).

The problem occurs when new elements are loaded using the infinite scroll and the BlogImageLoad function doesn't fire so the images don't get loaded into the newly loaded elements.

I have scoured this site and the closest I have come to working out the solution is using a callback function in the infinite scroll, the best looking solution being here: [Infinite scroll and the callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763308/infinite-scroll-and-the-callback)

Following that logic, and bearing in mind I'm slowly learning jQuery, here is my code, which doesn't work:

```
<script>

function BlogImageLoad() {
$('.xg_widget_profiles_blog_list .xg_blog_list .xg_module_body').each(function(){
var SP_Album_Cover = $(this).find("h3 a:nth-child(2)").attr('href');
$(this).append('<a href="'+SP_Album_Cover+'"><div class="SP_Album_Photo"></div></a>');
$(this).find('.SP_Album_Photo').load(''+SP_Album_Cover+' .postbody .xg_user_generated img:first');
});
}

$(document).ready(function() { BlogImageLoad() });

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

var $container = $('.xg_widget_profiles_blog_list .xg_blog_list');

$container.isotope({
itemSelector : '.xg_module_body',
});

$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '.xg_widget_profiles_blog_list .xg_blog_list .pagination.easyclear > li:nth-child(4) a',    // selector for the paged navigation 

 nextSelector : '.xg_widget_profiles_blog_list .xg_blog_list .pagination.easyclear > li:nth-child(4) a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)

itemSelector : '.xg_widget_profiles_blog_list .xg_blog_list .xg_module_body',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve

loading: {
debug: true,
msgText: 'Fetching more gold...',
finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
}
},

// call Isotope as a callback
function( newElements ) {
$container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
},

function( arrayOfNewElems ) {
BlogImageLoad();
}

);

});
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance!